# res.write() in express is not working for image tags

Tags: node.js, express

In express, I wrote this code

```
res.write("<img src='"+"http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png" + "'>");
```

I expected it to show me the image in this *[url](http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png)* but it shows me the complete code written under the quotation marks as text on the screen. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The SOLUTION that beautifully worked for me:

** **SET THE RESPONSE HEADER *CONTENT TYPE* (BEFORE res.write(<img...>)** **

[image]

You could either use `res.set()` or `res.setHeader()` like so:

```
res.set("Content-Type", "text/html") 

             OR   

res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html")
```

(both methods achieve the same thing: setting the content type)

Make sure you send the response with `res.send()`.

That should help you move forward!

Answer (score 0):

You can send plain html using `res.send()`:

```js
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
res.send(new Buffer("<img src='" + "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png" + "'>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

res.write() is used to send the response content(probably as a web page); so after what you wrote what you want, you should call res.end() or simply use res.send() instead.

to show image files, you should serve static files:

```
app.use(express.static('the/path/to/your/image/file'));
```

app is the object of express() you create at start.

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar and found this works to make the icon dynamic with the forecast code - Enjoy.

```
const icon = weatherData.weather[0].icon
const imageUrl = "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + icon + ".png"

res.write("<p>The temp in Brighton, UK is " + temp + " degrees</p>");
res.write("And the forcast is " + description + "<img src='" + imageUrl + "'>");
res.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const weatherData = JSON.parse(data);

const icon = weatherData.weather[0].icon

const imageURL = "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + icon + "@2x.png"

res.write("<img src= " + imageURL + "'>");

res.send();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.